# Microsoft Excel - Lookup Cell Value for Exact or Similar Match from a Range of Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way in excel I can lookup an excel cell value for an exact or similar match from a range of cells in a column. For example in the table below I expect a lookup function( **John George**) to return **John David George**

| staff | lookup text |
| --- | --- |
| John David George | John George |
| John Doe |  |

I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

A very naïve way could be:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","*"),A2:A3,1,0)
```

I mentioned naïve, because dealing with names is always arbitrary. You'll most likely find yourself looking to bypass all kind of edge-cases. With the current sample data it seems fit to swap out a space character for a wildcard matching 0+ characters. Just note that this *currently* does not yet prioritize an exact match over any approximate match.